# System() from c++ does not execute ImageMagick command correctly

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, imagemagick

As a part of my studies I am working on a command line tool to compute distortions on images. Currently, I am facing following problem:
I want to call an ImageMagick command via `system()`. The output I get is following:

> ```
> convert: command not found.
> ```

However, calling the exactly same function directly on the terminal works perfectly.

The command I am calling is

```
convert building.jpg -matte -virtual-pixel transparent \
         -distort Perspective \
              '7,40 4,30   4,124 4,123   85,122 100,123   85,2 100,30' \
          building_pers.png
```

From http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#perspective_projection

Of course the name of the image is different, this is just an example:

My code is the following:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    enterPoints();
    std::string cmd;
    cmd = create_cmd_l1();
    cmd += create_cmd_l2();
    cmd += create_cmd_l3();
    cmd += create_cmd_l4();

    system(cmd.c_str());

    return 0;
}
```

The method `enterPoints()` just collects the reference points, there is no problem with this part.

The `create_cmd-commands` create the 4 lines of the whole ImageMagick-command.
Calling all lines separately produces the same error:

```
    system(create_cmd_l1().c_str());
    system(create_cmd_l2().c_str());
    system(create_cmd_l3().c_str());
    system(create_cmd_l4().c_str());
```

Comment: Can you show the `createcmd_ln` functions, and show the result of `cmd.c_str()` ?

Comment: Why don't you use the [Magick++ library](https://imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php) instead of calling the command line tools via `system()`?

Comment: perhaps because of the lack of space characters between options.

Comment: try using the full path to convert in your system command